# palindrome or not what logical error in this

Tags: java, string, algorithm

what is the logical error in this code.In this non palindrome are also showing palindrome like "java"is not palindrome but code shows it palindrome

```
     package stringbuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        sbuffer.append(input.nextLine());
        StringBuffer sbuffer1=new StringBuffer();
        sbuffer1=sbuffer.reverse();
        System.out.println(sbuffer1);
        if(sbuffer1.equals(sbuffer)){
            System.out.println("palindrome");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not palindrome");

        }
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse()) changes the string content inplace and returns a reference.. Both variables are always pointing to same object.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the comments i have modified your code, which will work fine

```
package stringbuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        sbuffer.append(input.nextLine());
        String actual = sbuffer.toString();
        sbuffer.reverse();
        System.out.println(sbuffer);
        if(sbuffer.toString().equals(actual)){
            System.out.println("palindrome");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not palindrome");

        }
        input.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical error because you are working with references. 
Try this:

```
package stringbuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        sbuffer.append(input.nextLine());

        String original = sbuffer.toString();
        sbuffer.reverse();

        if(original.equals(sbuffer.toString()){
            System.out.println("palindrome");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not palindrome");
        }
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code to check how many palindromes are present in the sentence. 
This doesn't use any predefined method to reverse.

```
import java.io.*;
class String_Pallindrome
{
   public static void main()throws IOException
   {
       DataInputStream br= new DataInputStream(System.in);
       String word="",str,word1="";
       char c,ch;
       int i,j,pc=0;
       System.out.println("Enter the Sentence");
       str=br.readLine();
       System.out.print("The Pallindrome words are :- ");
       for(i=0;i<str.length();i++)
       {

           c=str.charAt(i);
           if(c==' ')
           {
               for(j=0;j<word.length();j++)
               {
                   ch=word.charAt(j);
                   word1=ch+word1;
                }
               if(word1.equalsIgnoreCase(word)==true)
                      pc++;
               word1="";word="";
            }
           else
              word+=c;
            }
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("Number of Pallindrome word= "+pc);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for check string is palindrome or not-palindrome

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter You String : ");
    String string = sc.nextLine();
    String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();


    if(string.equals(reverse)){
        System.out.println("palindrome");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("not palindrome");
    }
```